# RCM Exam Popular Selection Note Modifications

Tags: exam-grades, exam

For a piano RCM exam (let's say level 8), would an examiner likely reduce your score for making small adjustments to a "popular" piece to make the piece slightly easier to play?  For example, if the left hand is playing a 4 note arpeggio pattern, and you swapped the 4th note with a different note to make it easier to play, (1) Would the examiner likely notice? (2) If they did notice, would like likely reduce your score, (3) if they did, by how much?

Comment: One would hope the examiner would be marking on the performance of that particular version of the piece, chosen specifically for its position in the grading system. Any divergences would be marked down. Probably the *interpretation* would be open to conjecture, as those performance marks - pp, mf, rall, other dynamics, etc., are open to different interpretations, to a certain degree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Summary**

1. Yes, the examiner would very likely notice.
2. Yes, your score could change, but depending on the number and nature of the changes.
3. Small, unobtrusive changes — like changing a single note in a single arpeggio — would affect the score very little.

---

Based on my own experience as an adjudicator and a test prep teacher, I don't see a few small changes as causing significant problems.

Adjudicators are primarily looking for musicality and technical accuracy. So for a few minor changes, the adjudicator is likely to notice them — they're more than familiar with the music and will have a copy in front of them — but will probably just see it as a mistake. Score modifications shouldn't be significant unless 1) the performance of the piece is disrupted, 2) there are a substantial number of "mistakes", or 3) the changes are somehow enough to actually drop the grade of the piece.

However, a word of caution: if you find yourself needing to make changes, then you may not be ready for that level of exam. The exception to this would be a physical limitation, such as a hand-span that can't reach wide intervals.

Comment: Absolutely agree. If a piece needs to be changed, though, I'd advocate choosing a different one to present. There's always plenty to choose from!

Comment: If it's a popular piece then the examiner will have heard lots of unmodified performances, making the tweaked performance really obvious.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS, RCM allows you to substitute an etude for what it calls a "popular" piece which is more like a "modern" piece from pop music, movies or video games.   I didn't mean "popular" like a well-known classical piece (like Fur Elise or something).  Here's the 2022 list is here: https://rcmusic-kentico-cdn.s3.amazonaws.com/rcm/media/main/about%20us/rcm%20publishing/popularselectionlist2022.pdf